# android - Countdown then an action

Tags: android, eclipse, countdown, countdowntimer

I want to make an app , when you press a button a countdown has been startted.
When a countdown reach the end it looks how mutch you have clicked on the button , if its more then 10 it do nothing but if it under the 10 it has to activivate an action , like showing a pickture.

I also want to make a reset button.
When you hit the reset button the countdown is set on 10 seconds en when you click the countdown button again it starts over.

StartButton --->

```
|click = counter running|
|click after the first one = counting the clicks|
|if the clicks is above the 10 = it will happen nothing (break;)|
|if the clicks is under the 10 = it will show a pickture|
```

ResetButton --->

```
|resets the countdown|
```

I hope I sed it good.
I want to work with a "switch and case" system.

This is wath i have:

```
int counter = 0;

ImageButton finishhimbutton;
ImageButton resetbutton;
ImageView jb1;
ImageView jb2;
ImageView jb3;
ImageView jb4;
ImageView jb5;
ImageView jb6;
    TextView txtCount;





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mcounter);
        txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);              
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        jb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB1);
        jb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB2);
        jb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB3);
        jb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB4);
        jb5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB5);
        jb6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB6);
        finishhimbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.finishhim);
        resetbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reserbutton);







        finishhimbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
           switch(counter){


                case 10:
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 20:
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 30:
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 40:
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 49:

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finish Him!",        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 50:            

                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

                     break;

                case 51:
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    counter = 0;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

                    break;

                 default:

                     break;



                }

                }
            }



);



resetbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {               
            counter = 0;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your respond, is this better?

Comment: The First click should start a handler with a delay to reset the counter. Thats the only thing missing in your logic. And the reset button will reset the click count and stop the handler of course.

Comment: How do I have to do that

Comment: @DanielBo Please help me with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response

I did this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private Handler timer = new Handler();



int counter = 0;

TextView mTextView;
ImageButton finishhimbutton;
ImageButton resetbutton;
ImageView jb1;
ImageView jb2;
ImageView jb3;
ImageView jb4;
ImageView jb5;
ImageView jb6;
   TextView txtCount;





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);              
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        jb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB1);
        jb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB2);
        jb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB3);
        jb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB4);
        jb5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB5);
        jb6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB6);
        finishhimbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.finishhim);
        resetbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reserbutton);



        final Runnable hMyTimeTask = new Runnable() {
               public void run() {              
                    counter = 0;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);


               }

            }; 



        finishhimbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (counter == 1) {
                    timer = new Handler();
                    timer.removeCallbacks(hMyTimeTask);
                    timer.postDelayed(hMyTimeTask, 1000);

                 }

           switch(counter){

           case 1:
                counter++;
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                break;

                case 10:
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 20:
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 30:
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 40:
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                    break;

                case 49:
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Finish Him!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 50:            
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);

                     break;

                case 51:
                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                    jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                    counter = 0;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

                    break;

                 default:
                        counter++;
                        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                     break;



                }

                }
            }



);



resetbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
            counter = 0;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
            jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
}   
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
}
```

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a global variable handler, and on your first click you do this:

```
 if (handler == null) {
    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (!killed){
                //reset clickcount after 10 seconds and whatever should be done
                }
            }
        }, 10000L);
 }
```

and if you want to reset just wipe all you data. and set the killed global variable to true, so the runnable wont execute.

add it there, where your first lick is noticed.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter++;
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
        // should be fine right here
        ...
     }
```

Comment: Sorry that I am asking so mutch but I'm getting an error on "!killed"